# Subdivision surface creates a hole?

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCVEtLjpeB8

And when I add the *Subdivision Surface* modifier there's a hole at the bottom of my cup. I have no idea why this happens and how to fix it.

[image: bottom of cup has hole in it]

[image]

Comment: Maybe one of your verts isn't in the centre?

Comment: Can you share the file? Or at least show a screenshot that allows us to see the topology (Edit mode or something).

Comment: Anyway, it looks more like an black object overlapping than a hole to me. A hole wouldn't be that dark. But I'm still guessing here.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka I don't know how to post another image into a comment but it looks black on the solid mode, and when I toggle x-ray it just shows the same hole but kinda see-through? It's definitely not an object

Comment: You can edit you post and post a picture or share the blend file here -> https://blend-exchange.com/ and add the link to your post.

Comment: It really would be best if you could share the file, though.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka How do I do that?

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Okay I think I did it!

Comment: The file you sent does not have any black dot on it https://imgur.com/a/pUOuZAa

Comment: Have you modified the file before sending it? Dleted some objects, modifiers or anything?

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka I have the black dot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you haven't enabled the *Merge* option in the *Screw* modifier. Therefore you have many overlapping vertices in the center area. This creates a bad shading since you have set the object to *Shade Smooth* but didn't enable the *Normals* > *Auto Smooth* option in the *Object Data Properties*.

*Auto Smooth* will get rid of the visual effect, but you still have a lot of overlapping vertices, so you should definitely enable the *Merge* option, otherwise your mesh will stay unconnected in the center. By the way, the inner vertex of the glass bottom is not exactly in the center, so there is a hole. I would select it and set the Y value to 0.

[image: merge vertices]

The slightly off vertex:

[image: off vertex]

Comment: Is it Blender version related, then? I couldn't seem to have any black dot.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka I don't know, might be... which version are you using? The tutorial is for 3.2, I don't know if Rosie's using the same, I am on 3.3.1

Comment: I tried on 3.2 and 2.93.

Comment: Maybe it's a 3.3 thing?

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Might be.. but the good thing is, this way it was possible to detect some flaws in the object ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann i did everything you said and that fixed it! It's obvious, but I just started learning Blender like a month ago lol. Thank you guys so much for your help :)

Comment: @Rosie You're welcome. If my answer helped you, you might consider accepting it?